# Multi site live preview not working on index page

Tags: multi-site, live-preview, nginx

I'm on Craft 3.1.17.2

My multisite setup is using different domains.

If I'm on a.com, I can Live Preview everything on b.com fine, except the homepage.

I get the error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'b.com' from origin 'a.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

If I add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` to my Nginx config, none of the pages work and it complains about a duplicate value of (a.com, *).

Any ideas? Other questions I've browsed all suggest this has been fixed in Craft 3.1, and none of the docs indicate the I need to do anything to get this to work.

Comment: Did you solve this?